frequency channels and wifi
i always hear that when i want to use multiple access points i have to make them use different channels to avoid the interference of the radio waves. supposing that i have a router with built in AP(AP1) and i have another AP(AP2)connected to the router, now i just want to make sure that i understand this right, in the case of choosing same channel on both AP, they both are sending beacon frames and these beacon frames are advertising the frequencies channel they use so that my phone for example, when it connects to one of them uses the same channel, now if my phone connected to AP2 and its receiving data its actually selecting the frequency its using(channel) and filtering all other unwanted noise.
so if AP1 and AP2 sent two radio waves and at some point these waves "merged" together and reached my phone, my phone is going to select the channel it operates on, but in this case it wont know which wave to select, cz both have the same frequencies and same channels, but in case AP1 used a diff channel than AP2 my phone will be able to select the channel it needs and filter the other wave successfully without confusion, is that right or not?

That is just a single sentence and REALLY hard to read.

so you answered my question before and now youre complaining ?  anyways dw i will edit this @Zac67

Each Wifi channel (plus adjacent channels for 2.4 GHz) is a shared medium. If there are multiple SSIDs/networks on that channel, they all share the total bandwidth. When network channels are spaced apart, they become independent.

... and filtering all other unwanted noise so if AP1 and AP2 sent two radio waves and at some point these waves "merged" together ...

Not at all. There's only on sender transmitting at any time. There are protocol mechanisms that make sure of that (esp. CSMA/CA and RTS/CTS), and if it does happen the collision distorts the data and the current transmissions need to be retried.
(I'm ignoring MIMO here for simplicity. With (MU-)MIMO the spatial environment is exploited to make sure that each receiver only senses the intended carrier - with a reasonable SNR - while there are multiple simultaneous transmissions from the WAP.)

so i can understand theres only one sender transmitting at any time so theres no way 2 radiations from AP1 and AP2 to interfere, then why do i always hear that when you have multiple AP make sure that each is on a diff channel to avoid interference (and on a specific different channel-like 1, 6 and 11 in USA -)

Because two spaced channels have twice the bandwidth than a single one. Also, CSMA/CA reduces efficiency and RTS/CTS across WAPs isn't possible.

You’re assuming only one station on the network. What if you have several?

@RonTrunk so if i have several networks is what i said in my original post actually happening?

@Zac67 so i can understand that on the same network radio waves wont interfere but due to other factors (like efficiency or if i had another 'outer' interference with the waves) i should use different channel

Depends what is happening on the wired side. Any other traffic will interfere.
